# Exacttarget Calendar notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-alert, calendar, notification

is there any chance to receive notifications as soon as a Event on Calendar is deleted or changed?

Like it is in Sales Cloud where i can simply choose to send

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's no way to do this in realtime by webhook, trigger or similar. Indeed, there's no way to get this information easily after the fact in an automated way, either.

This "Interactive Marketing Hub" functionality was the focus of development between 2011 and 2013 where there was a rapid move to developing as many features as possible to sell a cross-channel story for acquisition.

I hope there's a Product developer or two on the case filling in some of these gaps. There are more shiny things that make the difference in RFPs or impress the chain of command these days, though. I'm not holding my breath.